# C# code to install a flash player from a particular URL (a link to a particular location in adobe website)?

Tags: c#, download

I want to write a C# code, which will prompt the user to install flash player from the location

> http://download.macromedia.com/pub/labs/flashplayer10/flashplayer_square_p2_64bit_activex_092710.exe

Can anyone kindly let me know how to do this.
Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

try this http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/download/detection_kit/ assuming that you would be detecting the flash player on client side in ASP.NET web application

Comment: No it would be helpfull if you provide C# code snippet which will install the flash player from the above location.